# iPad2シミュレータでは動くがiPad retina、iPad Airでは動かないのはなぜか

Tags: xcode, ios

iOS開発初心者ですが、無謀にもstoryboardを使わずにiPhoneとiPadで動くuniversalアプリを開発しようとしているところです。シミュレータでiPhoneとiPad2を選択して起動すると問題なく起動しますが、iPad retinaとiPad Airを選択すると起動時にエラーが発生します。

この情報から考えられうるエラー原因はなんでしょうか。
個人的には設定関連でケアレスミスをしている気がしているのですが、、、
同じような症状がでてこれで解決できたというような方がいたらご回答お願いいたします。

・エラー箇所

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));ここでストップします(Thread1:signal SIGABRTといわれる)
    }
}
```

・outputにでてきたログ

```
> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cedc3f5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cb75bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010da56cf0 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010d50aca9 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 40
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d509d49 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1075
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d508d22 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    6   FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000110a362a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce11abc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce07805 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce075c5 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ce06a06 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d508799 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d50b550 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    13  Add or Sub                          0x000000010c645703 main + 115
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f71a145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: 自分で回答を書いて解決済みのチェックをつけておくと、後から見た人にとってわかりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

Xcode6ではStandard Architecturesからarmv7sが外されており、
iPad Airなどで実行したい場合はBuild Settings->Architecturesに手動で設定値を追加する必要があります。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040497/xcode-6-standard-architectures-exclude-armv7s

Answer (score 2):

細かいところはわかりませんが、ビルド時のアーキテクチャ設定もミスなような気がします。
XCodeのビルド設定の項目に **Valid Architectures** という項目があります。
おそらく`armv7`などが設定されているのではないかと思われます。

iPhone5 以降の機種については、`Apple A6 CPU` 以降のCPUが使用されています。これは `armv7s`というアーキテクチャに対応しているため、こういうのが原因かなと思っていますが、定かではありません。

Answer (score 0):

**対処方法を発見したのでここに記載しておきます**

universal ではなくてiPad専用の設定にしてからビルドし、その後 universal の設定に戻してビルドしたら動くようになりました。原因はわかりませんが、これで動くようになりました。

---

*この投稿は @Kei Minagawa さんが質問文に記載した内容を元に、コミュニティwiki で個別の回答として投稿しました。*